# Amcharts: stacked columns with multiple series

Tags: javascript, typescript, amcharts, amcharts4

I have multiple series in one chart, such as seen in this codepen:

```js
let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
      chart.leftAxesContainer.layout = "vertical";
      chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = '# €';

      chart.data = [
        {name: "2011\nLorient", transport: 56, stay: 200, costByNight: 29, costByKm: 14},
        {name: "2015\nPoitiers\nLa Rochelle", transport: 96, stay: 54, costByNight: 9, costByKm: 23},
        {name: "2016\nRoyaume-Uni", transport: 160, stay: 332, costByNight: 47, costByKm: 62},
        {name: "2016\nBiarritz", transport: 185, stay: 516, costByNight: 74, costByKm: 27},
        {name: "2017\nRoyaume-Uni", transport: 258, stay: 355, costByNight: 36, costByKm: 24},
        {name: "2018\nSingapour\nVietnam\nTaïwan", transport: 1020, stay: 622, costByNight: 41, costByKm: 8},
        {name: "2018\nVietnam", transport: 753, stay: 294, costByNight: 49, costByKm: 8},
        {name: "2019\nCanada", transport: 1074, stay: 342, costByNight: 38, costByKm: 13},
        {name: "2019\nLorient\nGroix", transport: 77, stay: 190, costByNight: 27, costByKm: 20}
      ];

      chart.padding(20, 5, 2, 5);

      // Cities/countries names
      let categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
      categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
      categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "name";
      categoryAxis.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = false;
      categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 1;
      categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.wrap = true;
      categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.maxWidth = 100;
      categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = ".75em";
      categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.textAlign = "middle";

      /* FIRST CHART */

      // First Y axis
      let valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
      valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
      valueAxis.zIndex = 1;
      valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
      valueAxis.renderer.fontSize = "0.8em";

      // Transport
      let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      series.name = "Transport";
      series.dataFields.valueY = "transport";
      series.dataFields.categoryX = "name";
      series.yAxis = valueAxis;
      // Configure columns
      series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(100);
      series.columns.template.tooltipText = "[font-size:13px]Transport : {valueY}";
      series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

      // Logement
      series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      series.name = "Logement";
      series.dataFields.valueY = "stay";
      series.dataFields.categoryX = "name";
      series.yAxis = valueAxis;
      // Make it stacked
      series.stacked = true;
      // Configure columns
      series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(100);
      series.columns.template.tooltipText = "[font-size:13px]Logement : {valueY}";
      series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

      /* SECOND CHART */

      let valueAxis2 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
      valueAxis2.marginTop = 50;
      valueAxis2.tooltip.disabled = true;
      valueAxis2.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
      valueAxis2.zIndex = 3;
      valueAxis2.renderer.fontSize = "0.8em";

      series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      series.name = "Prix par 200km";
      series.dataFields.valueY = "costByKm";
      series.dataFields.categoryX = "name";
      series.yAxis = valueAxis2;
      series.stacked = true;
      // Configure columns
      series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(40);
      series.columns.template.tooltipText = "[font-size:13px]Prix pour 200km : {valueY}";
      series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

      series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
      series.name = "Prix par nuitée";
      series.dataFields.valueY = "costByNight";
      series.dataFields.categoryX = "name";
      series.yAxis = valueAxis2;
      // Configure columns
      series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(40);
      series.columns.template.tooltipText = "[font-size:13px]Prix par nuit : {valueY}";
      series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

What I would like to do and can't find out how is:
- Make the top columns getting the width of the two corresponding bottom columns (like some kind of colspan)
- Make the bottom series opposite, to have some kind of symetry (I tried opposite = true, but it made everything break)
- Have the common x Axis between the two charts

The expected result is this:
[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQEac.jpg)

Could you help to achieve at least one of those goals? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get two out of the three with the stacked value axis approach you're using.

Column series will always reserve space for other columns, regardless of whether there is a value present or not, so you can't force the top chart's column to fully expand. A workaround for this is to create a second, invisible category axis (disabling labels and grids) and assign the bottom series' `xAxis` to the second category axis:

```
let categoryAxis2 = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis2.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis2.dataFields.category = "name";
categoryAxis2.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = true;
categoryAxis2.renderer.minGridDistance = 1;
categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;

// ...
series.xAxis = categoryAxis2; //repeat for both bottom chart's series
// ...
```

This will make the top chart's column expand to the full width as the other columns are associated with a different axis entirely.

To reverse the bottom chart to stop from the top, set `inversed` to true in the value axis' renderer object:

```
valueAxis2.renderer.inversed = true;
```

The category axis cannot be placed in the middle, however.

Demo below:

```js
let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.leftAxesContainer.layout = "vertical";
chart.numberFormatter.numberFormat = '# €';

chart.data = [
  {name: "2011\nLorient", transport: 56, stay: 200, costByNight: 29, costByKm: 14},
  {name: "2015\nPoitiers\nLa Rochelle", transport: 96, stay: 54, costByNight: 9, costByKm: 23},
  {name: "2016\nRoyaume-Uni", transport: 160, stay: 332, costByNight: 47, costByKm: 62},
  {name: "2016\nBiarritz", transport: 185, stay: 516, costByNight: 74, costByKm: 27},
  {name: "2017\nRoyaume-Uni", transport: 258, stay: 355, costByNight: 36, costByKm: 24},
  {name: "2018\nSingapour\nVietnam\nTaïwan", transport: 1020, stay: 622, costByNight: 41, costByKm: 8},
  {name: "2018\nVietnam", transport: 753, stay: 294, costByNight: 49, costByKm: 8},
  {name: "2019\nCanada", transport: 1074, stay: 342, costByNight: 38, costByKm: 13},
  {name: "2019\nLorient\nGroix", transport: 77, stay: 190, costByNight: 27, costByKm: 20}
];

chart.padding(20, 5, 2, 5);

// Cities/countries names
let categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "name";
categoryAxis.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = false;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 1;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.wrap = true;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.maxWidth = 100;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.fontSize = ".75em";
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.textAlign = "middle";

/* FIRST CHART */

// First Y axis
let valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.tooltip.disabled = true;
valueAxis.zIndex = 1;
valueAxis.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
valueAxis.renderer.fontSize = "0.8em";

// Transport
let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.name = "Transport";
series.dataFields.valueY = "transport";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "name";
series.yAxis = valueAxis;
// Configure columns
series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(100);
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "[font-size:13px]Transport : {valueY}";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

// Logement
series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.name = "Logement";
series.dataFields.valueY = "stay";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "name";
series.yAxis = valueAxis;
// Make it stacked
series.stacked = true;
// Configure columns
series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(100);
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "[font-size:13px]Logement : {valueY}";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;

/* SECOND CHART */

let valueAxis2 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis2.marginTop = 50;
valueAxis2.renderer.inversed = true;
valueAxis2.tooltip.disabled = true;
valueAxis2.renderer.baseGrid.disabled = true;
valueAxis2.zIndex = 3;
valueAxis2.renderer.fontSize = "0.8em";

let categoryAxis2 = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis2.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis2.dataFields.category = "name";
categoryAxis2.renderer.ticks.template.disabled = true;
categoryAxis2.renderer.minGridDistance = 1;
categoryAxis2.renderer.labels.template.disabled = true;


series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.name = "Prix par 200km";
series.dataFields.valueY = "costByKm";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "name";
series.yAxis = valueAxis2;
series.stacked = true;
// Configure columns
series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(40);
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "[font-size:13px]Prix pour 200km : {valueY}";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;
series.xAxis = categoryAxis2;

series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.name = "Prix par nuitée";
series.dataFields.valueY = "costByNight";
series.dataFields.categoryX = "name";
series.yAxis = valueAxis2;
series.xAxis = categoryAxis2;
// Configure columns
series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(40);
series.columns.template.tooltipText = "[font-size:13px]Prix par nuit : {valueY}";
series.columns.template.fillOpacity = .8;
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of the "reversed" property, I played with "opposite" with no success.
To achieve putting the x Axis in the middle, I thought about playing with container and 2 charts instead of one... what do you think about it?

Comment: That can work, but you'll need to manually set your chart/axis margins if you want them to line up, which can be finicky. Definitely doable, though.

Comment: I'll try that then. Thank you for all your information!